# How to calculate how much damage a weapon will do at a certain level?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

I want to know if there is a way to know the stats of a weapon at any given level.

For example: if I have a level 1 Seigebreaker schematic it does x damage at level 1, I can also see that it does x amount of damage when it's level 2.

Is there a way that I can see or calculate how much damage it does at levels 3-50 whether it's just a chart or there's an equation? I would like to somehow figure out how much damage, DPS, magazine size and so on for every weapon and level.